# $\int_{1}^2 \log (t^2+t+1)\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{1}^2 \log (t^2+t+1)\mathrm dt$$

I 'd like to  calculate the above value.

my question is,

1) how to integrate $\log x$?

1-1) is there any way to calculate above value without integration?

Comment: try to integrate by parts

Comment: Ad 1): that won't help you much. 1-1) Yes, sometimes, many prefer to ask at Stack Exchange instead of calculating it themselves, but few get help without _any_ own effort. You may want to look up "integration by parts".

Comment: A) Integrate by parts. B) Complete the square $(t+1/2)^2=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \int_1^2 \log(t^2 + t + 1) dt &= \left[t\log(t^2 +t+1)\right]_1^2 - \int_1^2 t\cdot\frac{2t+1}{t^2+t+1}dt \\
&= 2\log7-\log3-\int_1^2 \frac{2t^2+t}{t^2+t+1}dt \\
&= 2\log7-\log3-\int_1^2 \frac{2t^2+2t+2-\frac{1}{2}(2t+1)-\frac{3}{2}}{t^2+t+1} 
dt\\
&= 2\log7-\log3-\int_1^2 2dt+\frac{1}{2} \int_1^2\frac{2t+1}{t^2+t+1}dt + \frac{3}{2}\int_1^2 \frac{1}{t^2+t+1} dt \\
\end{align}$$
These integrals can now all be dealt with separately, using other standard techniques.  It looks to me like integration by parts is the most efficient way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your first question is 'By parts'.the procedure is , taking log(t²+t+1) as first function,and 1 i.e. t^0 treated  as  second function.   Now answer of your second one is,no,in my point of view.

Comment: Aha. We can think of 1 equal to t^0 thx

Comment: Please telling me how can i type power of t be 0,

Comment: Use `$` around the expression, like this `$t^0$`